# Email not sending through 1and1 smtp host nodemailer caddy

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, nodemailer, caddy

In my nodejs express application, I send email using nodemailer when a new user registers and this is my email configuration, in my config.json:

```
 {
   "senderEmail": "email",
    "senderEmailPassword":"password",
    "smtpPort":587,
    "smtpHost":"smtp.1and1.com"
 }
```

and the transporterOptions is as follows:

```
var transporterOptions = {
    host: config.smtpHost,
    port: config.smtpPort,
    auth: {
        user: config.senderEmail,
        pass: config.senderEmailPassword
    },
    secure:false
};
```

Now in my local (development) environment, it is able to send email from 1and1 host but the issue is when I make my application live(production), it fails to send email and the error is as follows:
 Error: Connection timeout
and the stack trace is as follows:

```
{ Error: Connection timeout
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/*/*/*/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:591:19)
at SMTPConnection._onError (/home/*/*/*/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:564:20)
at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/home/*/*/*/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:256:18)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

The server configuration is done through caddy.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can we see the full stacktrace?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

[GCE does not allow outbound connections on port 25](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/). If 1&1 supports inbound email on a non-standard port, then you can use that. The page lined above has guides to sending email with Sendgrid, Mailgun and Mailjet (which use non-standard ports for this).