# Unable to send email from nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nginx, google-cloud-platform, nodemailer

Hi I am using nodemailer to send email. My nodejs application is deployed on gcp instance with nginx reverse proxy. My code is able to send email locally but not from server. Note that ssl is also enabled.

note that this command is not running from `telnet smtp.1and1.com 587`

but this is running `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`

This is my code

```
var transporterOptions = {
host: "smtp.1and1.com",
port: 587,
auth: {
    user: email,
    pass: pass
},
secure:true
};
```

Comment: `sendMail()` should call its callback with an error. What is the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email not sending through 1and1 smtp host nodemailer caddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993298/email-not-sending-through-1and1-smtp-host-nodemailer-caddy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has blocked port 587 at the instance level, so you won't be able to send any email using that port. For more on information, visit [Sending Email from an Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) which says:

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. By default, these outbound SMTP ports are blocked because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to. In addition, having a trusted third-party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet relieves Compute Engine and you from maintaining IP reputation with your receivers.

However, there is a step by step guide for setiing up called [Sending Email with SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid) which you can follow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/) and successfully able to send emails from port 2525.