# Have a form send an email to the user's inputted email

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a registration form. This form includes an email text box. How do I make it so that the code sends an email to the email that the user inputted?

Here's the code:

```
<form name="regForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateSignupForm()">
                        <div class="form-group mb-0">
                            <label for="formGroupEmail"></label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="formGroupEmail" placeholder="Email address"
                                name="signupEmail">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-danger">
                </div>
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html doesn't support sending emails, to do this you need a backend language.
I red you are using node js: so it is really simple. On the "send" button click you have to send a post request to the server (with the email content, title, and recipient). Then you have to make the server read the request and send the email using nodemailer (i think this is the best service).
to install nodemailer just write in the bash

```
npm install nodemailer
```

if you want to read a tutorial about nodemailer i would suggest you [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp), that is really well done.

Here is a simple example of what you are trying to do:
client.html

```html
<form action="/sendEmail" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="content">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and this is an example of how to send an email using nodemailer: but be careful, you have to implement this in a server (i would suggest you express, look at [this](https://expressjs.com/it/starter/hello-world.html))

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

note also that there are a few email api that can allow you to send an email from js without any server (for example [emailjs](https://www.emailjs.com/?ref=google-ads&gclid=CjwKCAjw8-78BRA0EiwAFUw8LMmyeQ8-h6Z7m17UuNFetwCr75aZqklgMR1nBeD_3yAnUvjBQLzR5BoCABkQAvD_BwE) or [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/marketing/sendgrid-services-cro/?extProvId=5&extPu=49397-gaw&extLi=10106948594&sem_adg=99604555857&extCr=99604555857-436931947323&extSi=&extTg=&keyword=sendgrid&extAP=&extMT=e&utm_term=sendgrid&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=GoogleAds_EMEA_Brand_(English)&campaignid=10106948594&adgroupid=99604555857&adid=436931947323&gclid=CjwKCAjw8-78BRA0EiwAFUw8LHCFwt6k4xBXqZUuGwbhLoh5BiKAWpFpha153vXq3l7uuG_phhlWRhoCm2wQAvD_BwE))

---

#### EDIT:

if you want to use express in your server (it would be the more logical chose) i would like to suggest you the following code, that creates an express server that looks for requests and sends emails

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 80;
var account_data = {email: "youremail@gmail.com", password: "yourpassword", service: "gmail"}

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/sendEmail', (req,res) => {
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: account_data["service"],
    auth: {
      user: account_data["email"],
      pass: account_data["password"]
    }
  });
  var mailOptions = {
    from: account_data["email"],
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: 'some subject',
    text: req.body.content
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
  res.send('Email sent');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

to run this remember that you have to install both express and nodemailer,
look [here](https://expressjs.com/it/starter/hello-world.html) for a tutorial about express

As @KevinPotgieter noticed nodemailer doesn't work for Google Cloud Platform, which hosting are you using?

Comment: Note: 'node-mailer' does not work if you host inside Google Cloud Platform. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995754/unable-to-send-email-from-nodemailer

Comment: @KevinPotgieter however thanks for the feedback, i'm gonna edit my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely needed to use a backend, You can use a service like SendGrid to send the mail. You'll need to use their API after you have created an account. I think the first 1000 emails a month are free

https://sendgrid.com/

Example:

```js
const sendGridMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sendGridMail.setApiKey(options.send_grid_api_key);

const mail = {
   from: from_email,
   to: recipient,
   subject: email_subject,
   html: html_text
};

sendGridMail.send(mail, false),
```

Comment: he is using nodejs, it is really easy to create a server and to send mail (maybe using express). however i would have suggested emailjs, isn't it better

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately html doesn't support sending mail. To do this, you need to use a backend (PHP, Java, Node js).

Comment: I'm using node js, how would it be possible to do this?